# How to dynamically cast value into data type in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a object named as stock which is below:

```
public class Stock
{
    public string Type  {get;set;} 
    public int? Quantity {get;set;}

    //.... It contains 25 properties
}
```

I need to read text file which format is below:

```
<Quanity_45|Type_Abc>
<Type_Abc|Quanity_45|Reorder_4>
```

In file, the each line represent one object. The line contains the complete object or some object property. What i need to do is to read the file and save the list of objects in DB. But i am facing an issue to cast property dynamically. I don't want to do below if-else-if-else blah blah code:

```
var columns = line.split('|');
foreach (string column in columns)
{
    string[] columnValue = column.Split('_');
    if(columnValue[0]=="Quantity")
    {
        obj.Qunaity = columnValue[1];
    }
}
```

if I do like above then i have 25 properties in my class and i need to have if or switch statement with 25 times.
What i want to do is to get property name and cast it into required type. I done this only in case of string like below:

```
string[] columns = line.Split('|');
foreach (string column in columns)
{
    string[] columnValue = column.Split('_');
    obj.GetType().GetProperty(columnValue[0])?.SetValue(obj, columnValue[1]);
}
//Obj is my object stock
```

It is working fine in case of string. But in case of type other than string it throws error. How i can cast it dynamically?

> Exception : Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'.

Comment: You can use Reflection to discover a property's Type at runtime.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @HimBromBeere i have updated the question. Please read at the end o question

Comment: @Zer0 yes. I want to get property data type and cast value into it.

Comment: well, **casting** is a compile-time-thing, where you provide the actual type at **runtime**.

Comment: Stock describes the types of the properties. Use Reflection to check which conversion to use to convert the text to the correct type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert second part to concrete strong C# representation yourself:

```
private object DeserializeValue(string input, Type toType)
{
    //here you need to deserialize 'input' string to value of 'toType' type.
    if(toType == typeof(int))
         return Int.Parse(input);
    if(toType == typeof(int?))
         return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? (int?)null : Int.Parse(input);
    if(toType == typeof(string))
         return input;

    throw new NotImplementedException(toType.ToString());
}

public T Deserialize<T>(string line)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(line))
        return default(T);
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    var columns = line.Trim('<','>').Split('|');
    foreach (var column in columns)
    {
        var columnValue = column.Split('_');
        var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(columnValue[0]);
        if(prop == null)
            continue;
        var value = DeserializeValue(columntValue[1], prop.PropertyType);
        prop.SetValue(obj, value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var stock = Deserialize<Stock>("<Type_Abc|Quanity_45|Reorder_4>");
```

**PS**: Every deserializer do string conversion (JSON, XML, YAML, etc), so your case is no exception.